# Help reading deadlock XML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock

Even with reading the Bart Duncan blog about reading deadlocks I still struggle with this.  I have included the XML from a particular deadlock.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <deadlock>
- <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process2fea928" /> 
  </victim-list>
- <process-list>
- <process XDES="0x64e18e3a8" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider+TransactionalSqlSession" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056" currentdb="12" ecid="0" hostname="APPSVM7" hostpid="3208" id="process2fea928" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" kpid="11776" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.240" lastbatchcompleted="2014-07-25T00:00:41.240" lastbatchstarted="2014-07-25T00:00:41.240" lasttranstarted="2014-07-25T00:00:41.230" lockMode="X" lockTimeout="4294967295" loginname="NTSERVERS\AX2012WEBPROD" logused="0" ownerId="9934810052" priority="0" sbid="0" schedulerid="16" spid="148" status="suspended" taskpriority="0" trancount="2" transactionname="MgdSqlSessionTran" waitresource="OBJECT: 12:277576027:10" waittime="4440" xactid="9934810052">
- <executionStack>
  <frame line="25" procname="Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a.dbo.proc_MSS_GetNextCrawlBatch" sqlhandle="0x03000c004f6ab01d5de1f8008ca2000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" stmtend="3504" stmtstart="3362">INSERT INTO MSSBatchHistory WITH(TABLOCKX)(CrawlID) VALUES (@CrawlID)</frame> 
  </executionStack>
  <inputbuf>Proc [Database Id = 12 Object Id = 498100815]</inputbuf> 
  </process>
- <process XDES="0x4212ea3a8" clientapp="SharePoint[OWSTIMER][1][Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a]" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056" currentdb="12" ecid="0" hostname="APPSVM7" hostpid="9480" id="process403a188" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" kpid="14060" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.360" lastbatchcompleted="2014-07-25T00:00:40.360" lastbatchstarted="2014-07-25T00:00:40.360" lasttranstarted="2014-07-25T00:00:40.387" lockMode="Sch-M" lockTimeout="4294967295" loginname="NTSERVERS\AX2012WEBPROD" logused="168" ownerId="9934809243" priority="0" sbid="0" schedulerid="11" spid="170" status="suspended" taskpriority="-10" trancount="1" transactionname="ALTER INDEX" waitresource="OBJECT: 12:277576027:0" waittime="584" xactid="9934809243">
- <executionStack>
  <frame line="1" procname="adhoc" sqlhandle="0x01000c00d14d6c19c006e5650400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" stmtend="294" stmtstart="24">ALTER INDEX IX_MSSBatchHistory ON dbo.MSSBatchHistory REBUILD WITH (MAXDOP = 0, FILLFACTOR = 95, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE, ONLINE = ON)</frame> 
  <frame line="133" procname="Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a.dbo.proc_MSS_DefragGathererIndexes" sqlhandle="0x03000c0018d2e62d8e07d6008ca2000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" stmtend="8816" stmtstart="8768">EXEC (@command)</frame> 
  </executionStack>
  <inputbuf>Proc [Database Id = 12 Object Id = 770101784]</inputbuf> 
  </process>
  </process-list>
- <resource-list>
- <objectlock associatedObjectId="277576027" dbid="12" id="lock4f20fdc00" lockPartition="10" mode="IS" objectname="Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a.dbo.MSSBatchHistory" objid="277576027" subresource="FULL">
- <owner-list>
  <owner id="process403a188" mode="IS" /> 
  </owner-list>
- <waiter-list>
  <waiter id="process2fea928" mode="X" requestType="wait" /> 
  </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
- <objectlock associatedObjectId="277576027" dbid="12" id="lock4d7444c00" lockPartition="0" mode="X" objectname="Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a.dbo.MSSBatchHistory" objid="277576027" subresource="FULL">
- <owner-list>
  <owner id="process2fea928" mode="X" /> 
  </owner-list>
- <waiter-list>
  <waiter id="process403a188" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" /> 
  </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
  </deadlock>
```

It seems like the following is occurring:

```
SPID 148 running the query (line 25 of proc Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a.dbo.proc_MSS_GetNextCrawlBatch)
INSERT INTO MSSBatchHistory WITH(TABLOCKX)(CrawlID) VALUES (@CrawlID)

SPID170 running the query (line 1 of adhoc query)
INDEX IX_MSSBatchHistory ON dbo.MSSBatchHistory REBUILD WITH (MAXDOP = 0, FILLFACTOR = 95, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE, ONLINE = ON)
```

However on the second executionStack there is a second frame, namely this:

```
<frame line="133" procname="Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a.dbo.proc_MSS_DefragGathererIndexes" sqlhandle="0x03000c0018d2e62d8e07d6008ca2000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" stmtend="8816" stmtstart="8768">EXEC (@command)</frame>
```

How does this affect the deadlocking?  Is this another process that was running at the time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as this is standard SharePoint maintenance the OP is unlikely to be responsible for the code or be able to interfere in it.  What they could influence, is the time it is run at.

dbo.proc_MSS_DefragGathererIndexes should only really be run manually and after your first crawl but not generally otherwise.  Can you confirm this proc has not been automated as part of a maintenance task?

**Recommendations:**

- double-check with your DBA dbo.proc_MSS_DefragGathererIndexes has **not** been scheduled as part of a regular maintenance job in your Crawl database
- if you can influence the SQL being run, consider lowering the deadlock priority on the index rebuild thread if possible, eg

  SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW
- if this proc does need to be run, consider [disabling the crawl](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219814(v=office.15).aspx) first as part of a small maintenance window.

SQL 2014 has a really nice feature called [Managed Lock Priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411(v=sql.120).aspx#Lock) (MLP), which sadly won't be of any use to you, but may be to future users.

Comment: Thank to you both for you replies, I will check out what can be done about this.

Answer (score 2):

Following information was found for victim process from the deadlock graph

1. `Isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)"` for process that was killed as part of deadlock.
2. `lasttranstarted="2014-07-25T00:00:41.230"` **`lockMode="X"`**
3. `procname="Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_3a7fefdbc44a48ef902a65ffb71c7d3a.dbo.proc_MSS_GetNextCrawlBatch"`
4. Problematic statement was:

   ```
   INSERT INTO MSSBatchHistory WITH(TABLOCKX) (CrawlID) VALUES (@CrawlID)
   ```
5. `TRANCOUNT=2`, open transaction is there

The other process which was in deadlock was:

1. Statement:

   ```
   ALTER INDEX IX_MSSBatchHistory ON dbo.MSSBatchHistory
    REBUILD WITH (MAXDOP = 0, FILLFACTOR = 95, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE, ONLINE = ON)
   ```
2. `isolationlevel="read committed (2)"`
3. `lockMode= "Sch-M"`

**Points:**

What is need of using TABLOCK hint and that too with read uncommittd isolation level. I hope you are aware about read uncommitted isolation level its not advised to use this isolation level in prod due to fact that you can read uncommitted data. Also TABLOCK hint will lock whole table and thus would hamper concurrency a lot.

To add to worse you did alter index rebuild  on **MSSBatch history** table which took (Sch-M) schema modification lock which would not allow any operation to occur as whole table is locked. Since in both queries table was dbo.MSSBatchHistory  its was higly possible that deadlock would occur. This looks to me as most possible reason for deadlock

**Suggesstion**

1. Please remove tablock hint and if possible read uncommitted Isolation level.
2. Please dont rebuild index during production hour rebuild of index is classified as maintenance operation andd should be done during maintenance window or when load is relatively less. Even though you used ONLINE index rebuild it does take short tem locks in the first phase of index rebuild.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting , Its not coming for me when I am posting answer